# What Control(s) would you use to represent this MS Word "Control"?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, custom-controls

The below is from a Word Form that I am bringing into a .Net Winforms App.  I am curious as to how some of you would accomplish this.  As far as I know there are not any existing controls that duplicate it's functionality, even if I remove the Total Hrs at the bottom.  Am I wrong?

Secondly, I am relatively new to WPF but I get the impression that if I must create my own control it will be significantly easier in XAML form than WinForms, correct?

Thanks,

[image: Custom Control]

Answer (score 1):

Use a `DataGrid` (WPF) or `DataGridView` (WinForms)

Comment: An "editable" grid I am assuming with a checkbox control, label control, textbox control in the 3 columns?

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Like I said, if I need to go "custom" at all I am going to go WPF I believe so I will look into it.